# On-screen keyboard not showing

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I'm using winforms project from [CefSharp Minimal Example](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample) running on a Win10 machine with multitouch screen. Cef version 49. The computer is without physical keyboard and should be used as kiosk but the problem is On-Screen Keyboard(OSK) is not showing when a input field(textbox) is focused on the web page shown in Chroumium browser. On the other hand when using Chrome on the same machine OSK pops up when an input field is focused. Windows is in tablet mode.
Is there a setting that can regulate this behavior or something else that needs to be done to enable this kind of behavior?

Comment: this sounds like a browser issue also sounds like you will need to write some code to check and or account for different browsers / behavior.. this would be my first guess

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#cefsharp-vs-chromium-embedded-frameworkcef

Comment: I feel so silly, I spent hours searching for the answer before posting and now following the @amaitland 's comment find there's a similar issue on cefsharp github page https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1691. Unfortunately I'm currently unable to try the downgrading solution, but if it works thank you  very much and sorry for the trouble!